# New window not getting the value on click [window. opener.]

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open, window.opener

I am trying to open a new window on click and send the current index value to the new window.

Here is my HTML where I want to change the value on click, default value is `1`

```
<input type="text" id='pageno' value="1">
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$('.page-list li').click(function() {
    var pageIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    var URL = window.location.href;
    var myWindow = window.open(URL);
    myWindow.opener.document.getElementById('pageno').value = pageIndex;
});
```

Comment: how about using `querystring`?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny if  i used  querystring, need to GET value  on new window. that is html page. not php/asp.

Comment: @Akhilendrayadav You don't need PHP/ASP for that, use `window.location.search`

Comment: That sound good, Please explain a bit .

Comment: Or `location.hash`, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny means that you do `window.open(URL + '?index=' + pageIndex);`. Anyway... your code has 2 problems. First, `myWindow.opener.document` should be `myWindow.document`. Second, you need to handle the window after onload event (which no need by using querystring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try to access the other window like that.
What you can do is add the information to the url.
Either using a hash `#1` or a query string `?pageno=1`.
Since you don't want to use any server-side languages I would go for a hash since that's easier to work with using JavaScript.

```
$('.page-list li').click(function() {
   var pageIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
   var URL = window.location.href + '#' + pageIndex;
   var myWindow = window.open(URL);
});
```

Then at the opened window you can acquire the page number:

```
var pageno = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "YOUR_URL?pageIndex="+pageIndex

and on newly opened window write below code in onload() method 

function onload(){
 var pageIndex = getParameterByName('pageIndex');
 document.getElementById('pageno').value = pageIndex;
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: Both answers  adding PageIndex(www.site_name.com/?pageIndex=3) on current window, New window opening as  www.site_name.com/.